# Create two datasets in SAS output

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

```
DATA survey; 
 INPUT id sex $ age inc r1 r2 r3 ; 
 DATALINES; 
 1  F  35 17  7 2 2 
 17  M  50 14  5 5 3 
 33  F  45  6  7 2 7 
 49  M  24 14  7 5 7 
 65  F  52  9  4 7 7 
 81  M  44 11  7 7 7 
 2   F  34 17  6 5 3 
 18  M  40 14  7 5 2 
 34  F  47  6  6 5 6 
 50  M  35 17  5 7 5 
 ;
```

Now I would like to create to files based on whether the records are Female (F)or NOT. Therefore I do this:

```
 date female other;

 set survey;

 if sex = "F" then output USA;
 else output other;
 run;


 PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

This however does not give me two sets with data depending on the F and M value. Any idea on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The name on the OUTPUT statement must match a name on the DATA statement.  USA should be FEMALE.

Comment: Also your code says `date female other;` instead of `data female other;`.  I guess this is probably a typo, but you should always run the code before adding to the question to avoid unnecessary issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look in the log window, do you see any error messages?

If your code is

```
if sex = "F" then output USA;
```

you should see an error, because  the DATA statement does not include a dataset named USA. If you change USA to FEMALE it should work.

Learning to read log messages is an essential skill in SAS.